# System call stat() converted to stat64() without any cpp option

Tags: c, linux, gcc, gnu, libc

I am running 32-bit SUSE Linux with kernel level 3.0.76.

I can see a stat() call in my code translate to stat64() in the strace output, without me specifying any CPP options like _LARGEFILE64_SOURCE or _FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<sys/stat.h>

int main ( int argc, char * argv[] )
{
    char * path = "nofile";
    struct stat b;
    if (stat(path, &b) != 0) {
    }
}
```

I compiled this file with gcc with no compiler options/flags.

On running the program,  relevant strace output is:

```
    munmap(0xb770a000, 200704)              = 0
    stat64("nofile", 0xbfb17834)            = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
    exit_group(-1)
```

Can anyone please tell me how the stat() was converted to stat64() ?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer seems to be found in the stat man page

> Over time, increases in the size of the stat structure have led to
>   three successive versions of stat(): sys_stat() (slot __NR_oldstat),
>   sys_newstat() (slot __NR_stat), and sys_stat64() (new in kernel 2.4;
>   slot __NR_stat64). The glibc stat() wrapper function hides these
>   details from applications, invoking the most recent version of the
>   system call provided by the kernel, and repacking the returned
>   information if required for old binaries. Similar remarks apply for
>   fstat() and lstat().

Basically, glibc always call stat64.

If you add a `printf("%zu\n", sizeof b);` , the `struct stat` sizes are likely different depending on whether you use _FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 or not, and glibc converts the `struct stat` between the kernel and your code.

Comment: I did come across that para but couldn't interpret it the right way. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

> I can see a stat() call in my code translate to stat64() in the strace output

You need to analyze the way syscall stat is wrapped on your system http://sourceware.org/glibc/wiki/SyscallWrappers (one way that you can see this code is to use `gdb`: execute this command under gdb: `catch syscall stat` and when you program will stop on this breakpoint get backtrace and analyze the function that called `stat`).

From http://linux.die.net/man/2/stat64

> Over time, **increases in the size of the stat structure** have led to
>   three successive versions of stat(): sys_stat() (slot __NR_oldstat),
>   sys_newstat() (slot __NR_stat), and sys_stat64() (new in kernel 2.4;
>   slot __NR_stat64). The **glibc stat() wrapper function hides these
>   details from applications, invoking the most recent version of the
>   system call provided by the kernel**, and repacking the returned
>   information if required for old binaries.

So it is glibc_wrapper that decides based on sizeof(struct stat) that it should call why stat64.

Comment: Thanks for that info on wrappers!